# TypeScript Modules in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 - 'require' is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 2 installed) I've created a new TypeScript-Project TypeScriptHTMLApp1 from the Template (using default project settings). After that, I created the new TypeScript file log.ts and copied the example code from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11.3 to that newly created file.

```
// -------- log.ts --------  
export function message(s: string) {  
    console.log(s);  
}
```

Next, I copied the following lines of code to the beginning of the app.ts files.

```
// -------- app.ts --------  
import { message } from "./log";    
message("hello");

class Greeter {
    element: HTMLElement;
```

When I try to run this project in Internet Explorer (from inside the Microsoft visual Studio IDE), I receive the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception at line2, column 1 in http://localhost:20728/app.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or bundle your scripts with [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). TypeScript provides the module syntax and compiles down into `require` calls, but does not provide a runtime module *loader*. You must include that in your page for the scripts to work.

In the browser, make sure to provide the [`--module` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and specify the type of module you're using. This will typically be `es6` for code you're running through webpack or `amd`/`umd` for older code using requirejs.

If you take a look at the TS compiler's output, you'll see that

```
import {foo} from './bar';
```

becomes

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
});
```

but note that `define` and the modules `"require"` and `"exports"` are *not* defined *by the compiler*.

If you're running in a node environment, the nodejs runtime provides the necessary functions for [commonjs module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) loading.