# How to fix '0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined'?

Tags: typescript

I'm a C# developer with very few web experience trying to learn Typescript. I am knocking my head on this error message.

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined
```

In a nutshell, I have build a Html application with Typescript code in it. I am using VS2015 as my IDE. Beside my app.ts and index.html in my project, I have 5 Typescript files where each one contains only one class (this is my C# heritage).

In app.ts, I tried instanciating a class in the window.onload Javascript event. Right above the window.onload, I try to import one of my classes.

```
import {ClassA} from "./ClassA.ts";

window.onload = () => {

    var cls = new ClassA();
    cls.doSomething();
};
```

When I try to run this code, I get the error message in my question on the import statement. With very basic knowledge of Typescript, I tried:

1. Export each class as it's own module. It didn't work.
2. Add the following paths at the top of app.ts. It didn't work.

   ```
   ///<reference path="require.d.ts" />
   ///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
   ///<reference path="node.d.ts" />
   ```

I'm pretty sure this is a rookie mistake from somebody with no experience in Typescript. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: May be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985591/typescript-modules-in-visual-studio-2015-update-2-require-is-undefined

Comment: Thanks @gile for the quick answer. As I'm so new to web development, I hardly understand the answer in this post. Do I put a `<script>` tag pointing to requirejs? Or do I include the `require.d.ts` as a comment in the app.ts that I have? Could you make any sense of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for the web you either need to use another tool for module resolution (webpack, browserify, etc) or don't use modules.

If you use the compiler options `outFile` and `"module": "none"` you'll get a single file without modules that can be ran directly in the browser.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "none",
    "outFile": "./lib/out.js"
  }
}
```

ClassA.ts (No export)

```
class ClassA {
    // stuff
}
```

app.ts (No import)

```
///<reference path="./ClassA.ts" />

window.onload = () => {

    var cls = new ClassA();
}
```

Which would transpile to:

```
var ClassA = /** @class */ (function () {
    function ClassA() {
    }
    return ClassA;
}());
///<reference path="./ClassA.ts" />
window.onload = function () {
    var cls = new ClassA();
};
```