# Require... now exports is undefined, What am I missing here?

Tags: typescript

Really like TypeScript, followed this supposed easy [sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-up-with-typescript/), the last part "**Export and Import concept**", bang! First got "JavaScript runtime error: require is undefined". Google found I need to install RequirJS, make sense, installed, bypassed it. Now, the same undefined message for '**exports**'.

This is what I've gone through:

1. I went through all 3 related post in SO,
   [TypeScript Modules in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 - 'require' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985591/typescript-modules-in-visual-studio-2015-update-2-require-is-undefined)

   [How to fix '0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103968/how-to-fix-0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-require-is-undefined)

   [Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

   Still not resolving.
2. Adding a TSConfig.json like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html), same.
3. Downloaded the supposed-ok source code, hah, his ended with `'System' is undefined`. Did npm install SystemJS, got "... open 'C:...\package.json', ... no descripton, no repository, ..., no license." Okay, added an empty package.json, same result.

So my questions are:

- What am I missing here for my own project?
- Are TSConfig.json and package.json required for TypeScript?

My project, **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

**Customer.js**

```
import { Address } from "./Address";

class Customer
{
    private _customerName: string = "";
    private _addressObj: Address = new Address();

    public set CustomerNameBase(value: string){
        this._customerName = value;
    }
    public get CustomerNameBase(){
        return this._customerName;
    }

    Validate()
    {
        this._addressObj.PlotNumber = 12;
        alert(this._addressObj.PlotNumber);
    }
}

class CustomerModified extends Customer
{
    Validate()
    {
        throw "throw from CustomerModified";
    }
}
```

**Address.ts:**

```
export class Address
{
    public PlotNumber: number;
}
```

**Customer.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./Address.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script src="./customer.js"></script>
    <script>
        var customer = new CustomerModified();
        try
        {
            customer.Validate();
        }
        catch (exception)
        {
            alert("exception raised: " + exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            alert("finally.");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

VS 2017 Professional v15.1 (26403.3) 
[image]

Comment: I think you're writing your javascript as if it was running on node.js, where require and import/export makes sense. You probably want to compile all your javascript output into webpack. Webpack takes care of turning your imports and exports so they work in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `import` and `export` which implies a module system. By default TypeScript will transpile to CommonJS modules but, as you are using RequireJS as your module loader, you need to use AMD modules.

Change your `tsconfig.json` to specify the module format you desire to use.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "wwwroot"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Additionally, you need to fix another problem with your code. When you define something in a module, it's only available to code that imports it. This means that your inline script should be removed and replaced with a module that contains the code and imports what it uses. Note that inline scripts are a bad practice anyway. It is however a reasonable to in-line your bootstrapping code as below.

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
  require(["app.js"]);
</script>
```

Now in `app.ts` add the logic that had been in the inline script along with the necessary imports

```
// app.ts 
import CustomerModified from "./customer";

var customer = new CustomerModified();
try {
  customer.validate();
}
catch (error) {
  alert(`error raised: ${error}`);
}
finally {
  alert("finally");
}
```

Of course, in order for this to work, you need to export `CustomerModified` for use by other modules which you have also neglected to do.

```
export default class CustomerModified extends Customer {
  validate() {
  // if you throw a bare string you won't get a stack trace.
    throw Error("thrown from CustomerModified");
  }
}
```

Note that and JavaScript the positioning of an open brace actually matters and should be appropriate as shown above - this isn't C#. It's also expected that you use lowerCamelCase for everything except constructor functions - this isn't C#.

Comment: `validate()\n{` is fine, it's just a different code style. What will get you in trouble is `return\n{}`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad TS usually goes with CommonJS, because I used `import` and `export` so it switched to RequireJS so that's why I got all the weird thing? If so what's my options to substitute import and export with?

Comment: I did all as suggested, **tsconfig.json**: `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    //"strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules","wwwroot"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}` Note, it didn't like 'strict' option even after npm an nuget installation of latest TS.

Comment: **Cusomer.ts**: `import Address  from "./Address";
class Customer{
private _customerName: string = ""; 
private _addressObj: Address = new Address();
public set CustomerNameBase(value: string){
 this._customerName = value;
}
public get CustomerNameBase(){
 return this._customerName;
}
Validate(){
    this._addressObj.PlotNumber = 12;
    alert(this._addressObj.PlotNumber);
    }
}

// original: class CustomerModified extends Customer
export default class CustomerModified extends Customer
{
    Validate()
    {
        throw "throw from CustomerModified";
    }
}`

Comment: **app.ts** `// app.ts
import CustomerModified from "./Customer";

var customer = new CustomerModified();
try {
    customer.Validate();
}
catch (exception) {
    alert("error raised: ${error}");
}
finally {
    alert("finally.");
}`

**Customer.html**: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        require("app.js");
    </script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad F5 got "JavaScrpt runtime err: module name app.js has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]). Trapped in require.js line 143.

Comment: @AluanHaddad array syntax works. Understanding [] array syntax is for dependency and callback, why would we still need [] array syntax if no callbacks here?

Comment: also 1) TSconfig.json is not required for TS? 2) what would I do to use Common.js vs RequireJS?

Comment: @Jeb50 Re: array syntax: Dependencies and callbacks are but one use this API convention, but another is to load multiple modules for execution. Actually an callback may pass to RequireJS's `require` function. RequireJS doesn't have the simplest API, but it's robust and gets the job done.

Comment: @Jeb50 RE: `tsconfig.json` please state which version of TypeScript you are using and I will be able to help you better. Re: *NuGet* It turns out I was wrong (I had a mental lapse and confused TypeScript with DefinitelyTyped declaration files, the later are no longer published to NuGet, but [TypeScript](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler/) is).

Comment: @jeb50 RE: NuGet: I strongly suggest that you acquire TypeScript (and all JavaScript packages) with JavaScript oriented package managers. Use NPM, or JSPM, or Yarn. Avoid Bower as it is effectively deprecated.

Comment: @Jeb50 RE: CommonJS: CommonJS modules were designed for Node.js but can be used in a browser by bundling them (creating a single file aggregate of all your modules wherein imports have been transpiled out), using tools such as Webpack or Browserify. Alternately, using a CommonJS format aware module loader such as [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) that can transforms them on the fly and does so orthogonally of bundling them.

Comment: @Jeb50 Since you are writing an application for the client, that is a to say browser and not Node.js) I suggest that you either stick with the AMD module format, or transition to ES Modules. Recent browsers can handle ES Modules directly and the aforementioned SystemJS polyfills this for older browsers. Using System modules (`--module system`) transpiles directly into a format that preserves ES Module semantics when compiling for browsers that do not support them, whereas CommonJS and AMD do not.

Comment: @Jeb50 sorry, it is a lot to digest, but you're in a brave new world.

Comment: @AluanHaddad this is about TSConfig.json, using NuGet console, `tsc -v` reports Version **2.7.2**.

Comment: @Jeb50 then Visual Studio should be picking it up. In `project -> properties -> typescript build` see which version is selected period Visual Studio has picked up tsconfig files for years. If you have one, the properties page will just show you the IDE tools version and state that other settings are being controlled by the tsconfig file. The package manager console is not where you want to look for this because that's not what Visual Studio uses to compile the code when you use compile on save

Comment: @AluanHaddad I kind of sorting it out, NuGet is mainly for .NET backend/server side. TS is actually for javaScript in .NET world typically for frontend, so it's better to go with npm. Here is the detailed [comparison](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117120/NuGet-NPM-and-Bower).  Back to `TSConfig.json` file, I've seen some projects don't have one, so again, **it's not required, right?**

Comment: @Jeb50 yeah you're getting the idea. That article is not very current however.

Comment: @Jeb50 tsconfig isn't _required_ but if you don't use it you won't have any reliable way to control compilation or type checking. Some IDEs offer a _few_ settings but even Visual Studio, which lets you control more than most, is not close to adequate. Go with a tsconfig file. Many parts of your tool chain including your IDE well respect it, using it to enable them to behave intelligently instead of guessing about things like where your project root is

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you very much for the in-depth info.